# Where to find FreeBSD sha256 utility source code

Tags: freebsd, sha256

FreeBSD provides set of utilities for computing SHA-2 hashes (sha256, sha512, etc). I want to find their source code. I don't need source code of the SHA-256 hash function itself, but I am looking for source code of the command-line utility, i.e. part which processes command-line options, input files, etc. I've cloned latest FreeBSD source code from the GitHub-based mirror repo, and searched for "sha256" over the whole repo, and it gave me a lot of matches, but still I couldn't find that exact one. Please point me, where I can find it, if you know. Note: please do not point me to Linux/GNU alternative, sha256sum, I am interested exactly in the code of the FreeBSD sha256 (and friends like sha384, sha512) utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line utility is `md5`, but the same executable has many different names. See [md5(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=md5). The source code is located at `src/sbin/md5`.

It uses a number of functions from the `libmd` library located at `src/lib/libmd`, but the crypto code seems to be in `src/sys/crypto/sha2`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the hash utilities come from [OpenSSL in the base system](https://wiki.freebsd.org/OpenSSL). For example

```
$ less /usr/src/crypto/openssl/crypto/sha/sha256.c

/*
 * Copyright 2004-2016 The OpenSSL Project Authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
...
```

You can upgrade the utilities from [ports](https://wiki.freebsd.org/OpenSSL#OpenSSL_for_ports). In this case, you can find the source in */usr/ports*. For example

```
$ cd /usr/ports/security/openssl
$ make fetch
$ make extract
$ less /usr/ports/security/openssl/work/openssl-1.1.1l/crypto/sha/sha256.c

/*
 * Copyright 2004-2016 The OpenSSL Project Authors. All Rights Reserved.
 *
...
```